# Android Studio ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, android, utf-8

Good day,
I am working on android project using Android Studio
My application was working fine

after couple of days I opened the project again and when I build the app I get this error

**ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.**

knowing that I haven't changed anything...

I checked online and I saw that it might be the XML files for the front end

I checked all the files and I made sure all have "" at the beginning

the error only show  with no other explanation

**ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.**

this is what I am getting while building before it gives me this error

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project D:\Android_Studio_Projects\Jupiter

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> **[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.**

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libjniPdfium.so, libmodpdfium.so, libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so.

> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> **[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.**

Comment: Also
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
      > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
      > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
      > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.